# Radio streaming nokia sdk 1.1 using http

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia, lwuit-form

I am working on a fm radio streaming project and i am implementing radio streaming for nokia sdk1.1 but i am not successful, i have followed many alternatives like

J2ME/StreamingMedia.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430_J2ME/StreamingMedia.htm

```
player = Manager.createPlayer("http://someurl:someport"); // this is not working and showing invalid url while same url works in media player i have checked and it is valid.
```

please give me some suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you look into rtsp, real time streaming protocol for j2me.

Answer (score 0):

I use input stream to create radio player.

InputStream is = Connector.openInputStream("`http://someurl:someport`");

Player player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mpeg");

player.start();